# Retaining leading zeros in Array output

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to this so apologies if I'm doing it wrong.

I have a VBA sub in Excel that I am using to expand ranges of values.

For example, 111-113 becomes 111, 112, 113.  The problem occurs when I have to expand values with leading zeros.  I have them all as NumberFormat = "@" and the pre-sub data does show the leading zeros.  They are lost somewhere in the processing and I suspect that its an issue with my variable types, but I honestly dont know.

I'm pasting just the relevant bits of the code below.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Dim ArrayData As Variant 
Dim ArrayOut As Variant
Dim X As Long
Dim D As Long
Dim Index As Long    
For D = ArrayData(X, 1) To ArrayData(X, 2)
    Index = Index + 1
    ArrayOut(Index, 2) = D
```

Comment: You are taking *111-113* and creating *111, 112* & *113* which leads me to believe that you need to sequence *D* from the lower to the higher value. Keep *D* as a long but use `Format(D, "000")` to stuff a text-based, leading zero value back into *ArrayOut*.

Comment: @Mdh111 I have rolled your question back to what you originally asked. If you got a new question you should create a new question, not completely change original one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the type of `D` to `String`?

Things only need to be `Long` if you're actually going to do something numerical with them, such as adding/multiplying them etc.

If the numbers have leading zeros, chances are they're not really "numbers".

Comment: Thank you for responding LondonRob and @Soren Holten Hansen.  I did try to change D to String.  I get "Compile Error: Type Mismatch".  Any thoughts?  I can try pasting more of the code if that helps.

Comment: This sounds like a different question to me. Accept either of our answers and start a new question, specifying *where* the `Type Mismatch` occurs.

Answer (score 0):

A cell formatted as `@` is a string-type format. Thus when converting this into a numeric format you will loose any trailing zeros (or get an error if your cells contain anything else than numbers).

You should therefore `Dim D As String` in order to preserve the format of the values in the cell.